# Change from jQuery UI slider to 'noUiSlider' - Function that updates slider on animation progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gsap

I have a GSAP animation that updates a jquery UI slider as the animation plays and the slider can control the animation progress... [Example Here](http://codepen.io/dchadney/pen/LwGBa)

I need to switch over to [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) for various reasons and I can't figure out how to make it work. Here is my jQuery UI code:

```
 totalProgressSlider = $("#totalProgressSlider").slider({
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step:.1,
        slide: function ( event, ui ) {
            tl.totalProgress( ui.value/100 ).pause();
        }
    }); 

function updateUI() {
    totalProgressSlider.slider("value", tl.totalProgress() *100);
}  

$("#slider").slider({
  range: false,
  min: 0, 
  max: 100, 
  step:.1,
  slide: function ( event, ui ) {
   tl.pause();
   tl.progress( ui.value/100 ); 
    }
}); 

function updateSlider() {
  $("#slider").slider("value", tl.progress() *100);
}
```

and here is my noUiSlider code so far:

```
$(".slider").noUiSlider({
  range: [ 10, 50 ],
  start: [ 2, 40 ],
  step: 1,
  handles: 1,
  slide: function(){
    /* ... */
},

  set: function(){
    /* ... */
}

  }).change( function(){
    /* ... */
  });


function updateUI() {
     $("#slider").slider();
}
```

I guess I don't really understand what 'event, ui' is and 'ui.value/100' and how I can convert this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Greensock's draggable tool:

http://www.greensock.com/draggable/

You can easily update a tween/timeline through the draggable instance and vice versa, update the draggable instance through the tween.

Take a look at this codepens:

http://codepen.io/rhernando/pen/Batoc

http://codepen.io/rhernando/pen/npBoF

Rodrigo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I also posted on the GSAP forum: http://forums.greensock.com/topic/8767-slider-control-using-jquery-ui-is-jumpy/  - I am not sure how to implement this to suit my needs.